# How do I bypass IsDebuggerPresent this execute?

Tags: encryption, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I'm trying to find ZipCryto Password from this execute, but when I open it in ollydbg and it always return to close programs because IsDebuggerPresent module.

I find the solution on the internet and try to
- Use ollydbg plugins (Hide debugger and IsDebugPresent)
- Try to NOP in IsDebuggerPresent module
- Try to force return 0 in IsDebuggerPresent module

There are not working.

I use signsrch to find where is handled the ZipCrypto password and it say

> 0041c57c 3052 function where is handled the ZipCrypto password [32.le.12&]

and where is IsDebuggerPresent

> 00435cd8 2545 anti-debug: IsDebuggerPresent [..17]

Can I bypass IsDebuggerPresent and find ZipCryto password in this execute?
Execute Link: https://mega.co.nz/#!PMdAjZab!bTO7VbZ6OjhJ_mgiigJ1BApDAgDeVWK_X-mKl9aMZw8

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open the file in a dissembler, find where it makes the call to `IsDebuggerPresent` and then ultimately closes the application (or shows an error or what ever), this piece of code you can NOP in order to disable the check.

You can read the ASM code with dissemblers like [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/), although they don't support editing, you can byte-edit the code (just fill the region you want to patch with NOPS) using [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php).

Comment: It's always close. I think it might have another protection module. Can you help me to find that? I can coding program, but I'm not professional with assembly and bugging.

Comment: If you find the call to the `IsDebuggerPresent` method and just NOP that you'll be fine. You can see that its at 0x00435cd8 (assuming from your main post).

Comment: I see in the signsrch window allot of CRC32 calls, CRC stands for Cyclic Redundancy Check and is used to prevent code editing. It probably doesn't kick you out because you didn't NOP the call to the IsDebuggerPresent method but because it detects you've changed it.

Comment: Can I find ZipCryto password in another method without bypass IsDebuggerPresent? I'm not well in assembly and debugging. Thanks you :)

Comment: Somewhere near 0x41c57c the password is being handled. Although, obtaining this requires some (basic) knowledge in Assembly and Reverse Engineering.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I think I should learn about assembly before and I will debug it again later. :)

Comment: No problem. You might want to mark this answer as answer as this will prevent other users from responding again!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie and now I mark as answer. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 2):

suppose your exe file name is a1.exe

do this:

- press `Alt+E` to go `Executable modules` window.
- Select a1.exe
- press `Ctrl+N`
- find `IsDebuggerPresent` in importes and select it.
- right click and click `Follow import in Disassembler`
- press `F2` on this opcode.
- Run Program and wait for break point.
- press some `F8` till returning to your code.
- search for some thing like `je` or `jnz` opcodes and change them.

Answer (score 0):

/GS- on the cl command line will remove this dependency.